# The process cannot access the file because it is used by some other process error in batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I am new to batch scripting..i am trying to execute the script to print file names using a loop and it runs fine. But i get an error sayin "The processs cannot access the file because it is used by some other process" in command prompt and it does not print some files when the scrpit is run the second time. I think this error is due to the output stream not being closed i.e. the text file where the file names are being written must be closed.

Plz can someone tell me if i am right and suggest me any solution. Part of the code shared below.

```
if %size% gtr 0 ( echo Success ) else ( echo Empty file %source% >> "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\AP\OutPutArexpoFileEmpty.txt" )

if %yd_frm_file% GEQ %mydate% (

echo %mydate% echo successful %source% >> "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\AP\OutPutArexpoAP1.txt"

)
```

Comment: I don't notice any immediate problems with this bit of code, other than possibly `if date1 GEQ date2` if the dates aren't integers -- but that wouldn't cause the error you're getting.  How are you populating `%size%`, `%source%`, `%yd_frm_file%`, and `%mydate%`?

Comment: Please inspect all `>` and `>>` redirections to locked file. Is there a redirection from a _non-internal_ command (e.g. `someprog.exe >> file`) among them?